# How to rate limit the fetch API in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, rate-limiting

I have a Vite.js App, React Template. In one of my components I want to fetch some data from https://wheretheiss.at/w/developer
API. I am using `useEffect`. Now, the documentation mentions that the rate limiting is 1 request per second. And here is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Info() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    longitude: 0,
    latitude: 0,
    altitude: 0,
    velocity: 0,
    visibility: "",
  });

  const getCoords = async () => {
    const data = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544",
    });

    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const lat = data.latitude;
        const long = data.longitude;
        const alt = data.altitude * 0.62137119;
        const vel = data.velocity * 0.62137119;
        const vis = data.visibility;

        setInfo({
          longitude: long.toFixed(4),
          latitude: lat.toFixed(4),
          altitude: alt.toFixed(4),
          velocity: vel.toFixed(2),
          visibility: vis === "daylight" ? "not visible" : "visible",
        });
      });
  }, [info]);

  return (
    <section className="info">
      <hr />
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>Latitude: </strong>
          <span>{info.latitude}°</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Longitude: </strong>
          <span>{info.longitude}°</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Altitdude: </strong>
          <span>{info.altitude} miles</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Velocity: </strong>
          <span>{info.velocity} mph</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Visibility: </strong>
          <span>{info.visibility}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I know that setting the `info` state as the dependencies array for my `useEffect` hook will determine React re-rendering the component in an infinite loop. My question is: How can I limit the fecthing for one time per second?
I cannot set the dependecie array as `[]` because I want to constantly fetch data, because the latitude, longitude, etc., are changing every second. I cannot leave it like that either because the app will throw this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Object {..., message: "Request failed with status code 429"}

which means my app is making to many requests above the rate limit. When I get this error, my coordinates are not being re-rendered anymore and they remain the same.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Rough idea - remove `info` from deps array and wrap everything inside of you useEffect with setInterval, which will fire every 1.2secs, for example, dont forget to clearInterval after that. If that is the only component that will utilize this api and there will not be any cases when you have 2 tabs of your app opened - that will work.

Comment: I agree with Sergey, setInterval also works with your scenario 

Comment: @SergeySosunov I wrapped everything into a setInterval, I cleared the interval at the end of the useEffect and now I get:
`Module "timers" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "timers.clearInterval" in client code.get`

Comment: Not sure why it tells about module "timer" (which is nodejs) if those methods are just `window` methods. Try using window.setInterval and window.clearInterval.

Comment: @SergeySosunov it changes nothing. Still the same error. I will go and try with axios-retry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'axios-retry' npm package in your environment. It has the capabilities you need to use in your environment.

Comment: I have just checked the documentation. They have `retries, retryCondition, shouldResetTimeout, retryDelay, onRetry` options in the request. Especially `retries` parameter may use for `rate-limit` usage. Please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: @SelimEmreToy `axios-rety` sounds great. I will go through the documentation and try both solutions, and finally see which one fits the best. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if I wrap the useEfrect into a setTimeout, to delay the useEffect? Basically the component should be re-rendered every other 1s, to respect the rate limit, because of the setTimeout. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**step 1:**
import the react-debouncing lib
npm i loadash

> now use the loadash's debounce to debounce the function so the
> function will run only for 1sec so the request will also get limited
> to 1req per sec
>
> here is the modified code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { debounce } from 'loadash';

export default function Info() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    longitude: 0,
    latitude: 0,
    altitude: 0,
    velocity: 0,
    visibility: "",
 });

  const getCoords = async () => {
    const data = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544",
    });

    return data;
  };

let debouncedReq = debounce(()=>{
 fetch("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const lat = data.latitude;
        const long = data.longitude;
        const alt = data.altitude * 0.62137119;
        const vel = data.velocity * 0.62137119;
        const vis = data.visibility;

        setInfo({
          longitude: long.toFixed(4),
          latitude: lat.toFixed(4),
          altitude: alt.toFixed(4),
          velocity: vel.toFixed(2),
          visibility: vis === "daylight" ? "not visible" : "visible",
        });
      });
}, 1000) // now the function is debounced for 1000ms

  useEffect(() => {
   debouncedReq()
  }, [info]);

  return (
    <section className="info">
      <hr />
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>Latitude: </strong>
          <span>{info.latitude}°</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Longitude: </strong>
          <span>{info.longitude}°</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Altitdude: </strong>
          <span>{info.altitude} miles</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Velocity: </strong>
          <span>{info.velocity} mph</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Visibility: </strong>
          <span>{info.visibility}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just a quick thing: `loadash` package has been deprecated. I will use `lodash` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code relies on the fetch call succeeding to have another scheduled afterwards (triggered by `setInfo` being called with new data) and these are scheduled to run one after the other without any delay which quickly results in the rate limit quickly being hit.

[wheretheiss.at](https://wheretheiss.at) rate limiting is roughly documented on [their API page](https://wheretheiss.at/w/developer) but they also indicate that you should check out the `X-Rate-Limit-*` headers returned by their server to know more info about it:

```http
X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 350
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 193
X-Rate-Limit-Interval: 5 minutes
```

This means you can query slightly more often than every second so you can use `setInterval` to schedule your API calls:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    fetch('https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const lat = data.latitude;
          const long = data.longitude;
          const alt = data.altitude * 0.62137119;
          const vel = data.velocity * 0.62137119;
          const vis = data.visibility;

          setInfo({
            longitude: long.toFixed(4),
            latitude: lat.toFixed(4),
            altitude: alt.toFixed(4),
            velocity: vel.toFixed(2),
            visibility: vis === 'daylight' ? 'not visible' : 'visible',
          });
        });
  }, 1_000);
  return () => { clearInterval(interval) };
}, [setInfo])
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hlwp4d?file=Info.tsx)

Comment: does `X-Rate-Limit-Interval: 5 minutes` means that I can query the API only for 5 minutes?

Comment: It does not. It means that you can query `X-Rate-Limit-Limit` times per `X-Rate-Limit-Interval`. So here, it's 350 times per period of 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a shot and come back with an update.

Comment: At the useEfrect's deps array is info or you have misspelled that?

Comment: No it's `setInfo`. There's no need to make use of `info` in the `useEffect` callback. Also, you can check the code running by following the [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hlwp4d?file=Info.tsx) I included.

Comment: You can also [check the header in your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-syfazi?file=Info.tsx) and decide what to do regarding scheduling.